# Genitive case usage without articles

Tags: grammatical-case

> [...] Und auch angesichts der Auswirkungen **konventioneller** Tierhaltung auf das Weltklima ist ein Umdenken sinvoll.

Why is the ending of konventionll "er" in the above? I am assuming the above it is in the genitive case, but I don't really understand how genitive without articles work.

Comment: It's the same as with other cases - adjectives decline differently depending on whether there is an article or not.

Comment: http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/reference/complete-declension-tables/ See under No Article, Plural, GEN. The ending is the same for all inflected adjectives.

Comment: My question is why is it genitive @Rha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The genitive is equivalent to the preposition *of* in the English translation:

> [...] the effects **of** conventional livestock breeding [...]

The English translation of *konventioneller Tierhaltung* contains no article, just like the German phrase.

Comment: Why did we not use article here?

Comment: An abstract term like *Tierhaltung* does not require an article.

Comment: What is this rule called? First time I heard it @Rha

Comment: This isn't a rule but concepts are often used without an article. *Tierhaltung* is a concept. It's made from the phrase *Tiere halten*. It's the concept behind that action.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no determiner at all, the adjective gets the strong ending. That is the same ending as the definite article for that case, number, gender has, but for one exception: in genitive singular masculine and neuter, the strong adjective ending is -en, not -es.

But your example has the noun *die Tierhaltung* and thus:

> der Auswirkungen d**er** Tierhaltung
>
> der Auswirkungen konventionell**er** Tierhaltung

Comment: Same doubt as Rha's answer

Comment: You can also say *der Auswirkungen der konventionellen Tierhaltung*. The difference is that this is **definite** as it has a definite article while *Tierhaltung* in your example sentence hasn't and isn't.

Comment: @SBrian why would one use an article? You do the same in English, too: ...the consequences of conventional lifestock breeding... There is no definitive nor an indefinitive article there either when you are talking of a general concept.